# Upgrade from spring 3.0.4 to 3.2.2 causes 405 get not supported for stylesheet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If I build my application with spring 3.0.4, the stylesheet is downloaded no problem.

If I build it with 3.2.2.release, however, I get a 405 error saying GET is not supported when it tries to get the stylesheet.

No other changes have been made.

I am deploying to Glassfish

Does anyone have any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any ideas what could cause this?

Potentially many things.  (My guess would be that some request is being redirected to the wrong place by SpringSecurity.)

But rather than guessing, you would be better off gathering some concrete evidence of what is happening:

- In the web browser, figure out exactly what the pattern of requests and responses is.  For instance, if there is a redirect happening, find out what it is redirecting too.
- On the server side, enable debug logging for your application, the Spring stack, and if necessary Glassfish.  This should provide you with more clues as to what is happening.